# Select indices in tensorflow that fulfils a certain condition

Tags: tensorflow

I wish to select elements of a matrix where the coordinates of the elements in the matrix fulfil a certain condition. For example, a condition could be : (y_coordinate-x_coordinate) == -4
So, those elements whose coordinates fulfil this condition will be selected. How can I do this efficiently without looping through every element?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```py
iterSession = tf.InteractiveSession()

vals = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
arr = tf.constant([[x, y] for x in range(3) for y in range(3) if -1 <= x - y <= 1])

arr.eval()
# >> array([[0, 0],
# >>        [0, 1],
# >>        [1, 0],
# >>        [1, 1],
# >>        [1, 2],
# >>        [2, 1],
# >>        [2, 2]], dtype=int32)

tf.gather_nd(vals, arr).eval()
# >> array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
```

---

Or [tf.boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask):

```py
iterSession = tf.InteractiveSession()

vals = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
arr = tf.constant([[-1 <= x - y <= 1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)])

arr.eval()
# array([[ True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True],
#        [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

tf.boolean_mask(vals, arr).eval()
# array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  8.,  9.], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: thanks but I can't use for loops as my matrix shapes are dynamic.

Comment: @ray.r.chua The size of your matrix changes as the neural network runs? Could you give more details? Or do you mean that you calculate the indices in a dynamic way?

Comment: the size of my matrixes changes as my input matrix does not have a fixed size.